# Weak solution to Poisson equation

Tags: elliptic-pde

Assume that $g$ is defined bounded function on the union of $D^+$ and $D^-$ of upper unit disk and lower unit disk. Assume that $u$ is a weak solution of the Poisson equation $\Delta u =g$ on $D'=D^+\cup D^=$ so that $u$ has continuous extension to the unit disk $D=\{z=x+i y: x^2+y^2<1\}$. Does this mean that $u$ is the weak solution of $\Delta u=g$ on the unit disk (where we can set $g$ to be zero on $[-1,1]$).